# IOS: problem with nsarray layout

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, text-files

In this code I read a file txt: this txt file have information in this way:
one#two#three#four#five;one#two#three#four#five;

```
- (void) readFile{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.txt"];
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

if (!fileString) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
} 

NSMutableArray *itemDB = [[fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] mutableCopy]; 
[itemDB removeLastObject];

NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i<[itemDB count]; i++) {

    NSArray *datiItemDB = [[itemDB objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
    [returnArray addObject: datiItemDB]; 
}

one = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray*)returnArray]; 

[returnArray release];
}
```

the result of nslog of this array is

```
2011-07-04 10:01:16.847 Project[254:707] array one:(
    (
    "(\n    0,\n    1,\n    12,\n    \"2011-07-04 08:00:41 +0000\",\n    \"2011-07-15 00:00:00 +0000\",\n    \"\",\n    0,\n    0,\n        (\n    ),\n    \"\"\n)"
)
)
```

but I want that the result of nslog is

```
2011-07-04 09:52:07.281 Project[230:707] array one:(
    (
    0,
    1,
    1,
    "2011-07-04 07:45:15 +0000",
    "2011-07-04 07:45:15 +0000",
    "",
    0,
    0,
            (
    ),
    ""
)
)
```

Why I have "/n" symbols, and how can I remove it from my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want to put the first part of the text file in an array? I think you are overcomplicating the problem. What about something like this:

```
NSString *inputString = @"one#two#three#four#five;one1#two2#three3#four4#five5;";
NSArray *arrayFromInputString = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
NSArray *component1 = [[arrayFromInputString objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSLog(@"1: %@", [component1 description]);
NSArray *component2 = [[arrayFromInputString objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSLog(@"2: %@", [component2 description]);
```

If you run that, the output is

```
[777:207] 1: (
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four,
    five
)
[777:207] 2: (
    one1,
    two2,
    three3,
    four4,
    five5
)
```

Is this what you wanted? If not, can you try to explain better?

Comment: Ok, but this is not clear in your question. Try NSArray *arrayFromInputString = [inputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#;"]];

Comment: I have ever in nslog 2011-07-04 10:44:54.378 Project[331:707] arrayFromInputString:(
    "(\n    0,\n    1,\n    11,\n    \"2011-07-04 08:39:08 +0000\",\n    \"2011-07-14 00:00:00 +0000\",\n    \"\",\n    0,\n    0,\n        (\n    ),\n    \"\"\n)",
    ""
)

Comment: I understand my problem: when I write my string I do
NSString *outputString = [[array componentsJoinedByString:@"#"] stringByAppendingString:@";"];